# Can I call a command window to run while also calling SQL?

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, cmd

I have a Batch file.  I have a SQL query.  Each works fine the way it is. 
 Currently I call the batch file, wait for it to finish.  Then I call the query.  Then I process all the data from each.

The problem is, the batch file now takes about 13 minutes to extract zip files, `findstr` within those files, etc, due to the size the files have grown to due to code changes in the application that creates them.

I want to save time by calling the batch file to start the process, then simultaneously call the SQL query which runs for 1-3 minutes before returning the results.  I can process the SQL results before the batch is finished spitting out its results.  But beyond that, I need the batch to finish before proceeding further.

Through a series of Calls and Waits, can I make this happen?  16 minutes total is a LONG time.

Alternatively, does anyone know of a faster way to `findstr` within ZIP files?  Each ZIP only has one file in it.

**UPDATE:**
The query is in no way related to the zip files, but i need data from both sources in order to process all data relevant to my work.
The query pulls data from SQL Server and drops it into a sheet.  Excel takes data compiled by the `findstr` conducted in the batch files and creates more sheets.
The zipped files are on a network and range from 1.5 - 5.5 MB, the extracted files are 18 - 62 MB roughly.

Comment: What is your driving application - batch file or excel/vba ? Which db do you query with SQL? Which is your query processor ? Do you use it to query/update an excel file? A general idea would be to loop over zip files and to compose a sequence of commands for each file, along the lines of  `for i=<zip names> do <unzip> && <query>`. Otoh it might be a better idea to unzip concurrently, keeping several cores of your cpu busy (check with the process explorer whether the unzipping runs on 1 or more cores), and leaving the rest of your workflow as-is.

Comment: Hard to give advice without knowing more.  If the zips are large files on a network they will be slow.  You could try copying them to a local file to unzip and process?  It *might* speed things up.

Comment: @Gareth - You're right, extracting from the local drive will be faster.  I did that back in the day when the logs were large originally, then they were updated to be smaller, so I went back to doing it directly over the network.  Now the files are large again.  Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Still hopeful these processes can run in parallel, though.

Comment: Note that VBA is single threaded only by design. That means all commands are run sequentially, parallel run of commands is not possible. Please also include your code (or a [mcve]) into the question in order to help you.

Comment: It might be possible to do what you need inside SQL and save a lot of these steps